# Attachment Migration from Microsoft Dynamics 365 to SharePoint

Tags: dynamics-crm, sharepoint-online, dynamics-365

We have files present in CRM which needs to be migrated to Sharepoint. For eg. email attachments, notes attachments etc. Please let us know the fastest way w.r.t execution time to do the same. Waiting for valuable inputs.
Thank You!